# why response of restTemplate.exchange return null?

Tags: spring-boot, exception, spring-rest, spring-web

I have blow code and my web service works well but does not return response :

```
ResponseEntity<Object> reponse=null;
        try {
            reponse = restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Object.class);

        } catch (HttpStatusCodeException e) {
            System.out.println("reponse="+reponse);


        }
```

my question is that,
why

**response**

is null but

**restTemplate.exchange(url, HttpMethod.POST, requestEntity, Object.class)**

is not  null?

Comment: Use correct case shift in subject and read "How to ask".

Answer (score 1):

I was incorrectly searching for errors in response entity. But it is available in the exception.

```
} catch (HttpClientErrorException e) {
      System.out.println(e.getStatusCode());
      System.out.println(e.getResponseBodyAsString());
    }
```